# How to have a bash command in my directory?

Tags: bash

I have a Ruby project in a directory. When someone is in this directory, I want the command 'foo command args' to alias to 'rake command args'. Is there a good way to basically write a bashrc file in my directory that gets sourced automatically when the user cds into the directory? I want it to be done automatically.

Comment: The user would have to have code in their own `.bashrc` that wraps `cd`. There exist programs that do this (most notably `rvm`), but it's very poor practice -- most notably, a substantial security risk.

Comment: ...and even `rvm` disables that functionality by default, prompting the user to review whether they trust a given directory's configuration before sourcing it.

Comment: (Just to be sure: By "my directory", you mean the single directory in which you want that command's directives to apply? The question could use some additional precision in its drafting).

Comment: ...and then being able to cleanly revert / unset environment changes on *leaving* a directory, without reverting other shell-state modifications made while within it, is a whole different ball of worms.

Comment: Why do you want this? It seems like an unwise and unintuitive idea to me. Command names don't change when I `cd` around. If I want to run something in the current directory type `./` first.

Answer (score 0):

**This is very bad security practice. Don't do it.**

In your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:./.bin
```

In your directory:

```
mkdir -p .bin
cat >.bin/foo <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
exec rake "$@"
EOF
chmod +x .bin/foo
```

Comment: Indeed. But... well, if someone is going to do a thing, better that they do it in a way that's dangerous rather than a way that's insanely dangerous. In short, I'm trying to front-run the even worse answers (like rvm's approach of wrapping `cd`).